# Creative SDK Image component - Image Editor UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, adobecreativesdk

I completed all step of Creative SDK Image component .But,how can i convert this block into Swift language..

```
id<AdobeImageEditorRender> render = [photoEditor enqueueHighResolutionRenderWithImage:highResImage

         completion:^(UIImage *result, NSError *error) {

            if (result) {

            } else {

            }
}];



// Provide a block to receive updates about the status of the render
[render setProgressHandler:^(CGFloat progress) {

 print("Do something")

 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly this, since I don't have the SDK installed, but it should be very close to this:

```
    let render = photoEditor.enqueueHighResolutionRenderWithImage(image) { result, error in
         if let result = result {
              // do something with result. 
         } else {
              // do something with error. 
         }
    }

    render.progressHandler = { progress in 
        // update progress, if 
    }
```

if you reference self in the blocks, you need to put  [unowned self] after the brace like this:

```
    render.progressHandler = { [unowned self] progress in 
        self.updateProgress(progress)
    }
```